# If statement always giving the same answer

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Practice {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    System.out.println("Enter the number of treats you have:");
    Scanner treatsScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int treats = (treatsScanner.nextInt());

    System.out.println("Enter the number of hamsters you have:");
    Scanner hamstersScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int hamsters = (hamstersScanner.nextInt());

    System.out.println("How many treats does each hamster need?");
    Scanner neededTreatsScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int neededTreats = (neededTreatsScanner.nextInt());     

    int treatsPerHamster = treats / hamsters;
    boolean enoughTreats = treatsPerHamster >= neededTreats;        

    if (enoughTreats = true) {
        System.out.println("There are enough treats for all the hamsters!");
    }
    else if (enoughTreats = false) {
        System.out.println("Oh no! There aren't enough treats!");        
    }

}
}
```

Can someone explain to me why this program returns "There are enough treats for all the hamsters!" regardless of whether "neededTreats" > "treatsPerHamster"?

Thank you.

Comment: Another thing. If you are going to put a boolean as a condition you should not do '==' at all. I was taught at least that it is bad practice. It is like saying if ( ( enoughTreats is true ) is true )

Comment: While it has nothing to do with the question, what do you need all those Scanners for?

Comment: Additional to the answers below. There is no point in your else if. boolean's can either be true or false, nothing else. So just use `if(){...}else{...}`

Comment: "enoughTreats = false" always returns true because the assign does happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning the value true to enoughtreats.

Try using the equality operator rather than assignment:

```
if (enoughtreats == true) {
...
}
```

or simply:

```
if(enoughtreats) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use `==` instead of `=`

```
    if (enoughTreats == true) {
        System.out.println("There are enough treats for all the hamsters!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Oh no! There aren't enough treats!");        
    }
```

Remember that `==` is the comparison operator and `=` is the assignment operator.

And as Mike mentioned, just having `if(enoughTreats)` will do the trick for you. No need to use `==` operator!

As a matter of fact, you don't need the boolean variable `enoughTreats` at all. You could just write your condition like so:

```
if (treatsPerHamster >= neededTreats) {
    // do one thing
}
else {
    // do other
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In java, the '=' operator assigns a value to a variable. In this case,

```
if (enoughTreats = true)
```

assigns the value 'true' to 'enoughTreats' and then checks if 'enoughTreats' is true (which it always will be).

Instead, you want to put

```
if (enoughTreats == true)
```

so that it will check if enoughTreats is true or false.

Answer (score 1):

Use `==` for equality, not `=`.

Answer (score 1):

`if (enoughTreats = true)`

By using `=`, you are assigning `true` to `enoughTreats`.  Use the `==` comparison operator instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change these two statements

```
if (enoughTreats = true) 

else if (enoughTreats = false)
```

into

```
if (enoughTreats == true) 

else if (enoughTreats == false)
```

You could also shorten the code and get the exact same effect by simply typing this below:

```
if (enoughTreats)

else
```

If you put a boolean variable inside of the parenthesis of an if statement by itself, the if statement will check to see if it's true, thus you wouldn't need to type '== true.'  You could also replace the else if statement in your code with a simple 'else' because if the enoughTreats variable is not equal to true, the else code will automatically execute without you having to specifically state a condition.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to note and to add to the listed answers

- Just one scanner is enough `Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);`
- Braces around `(...Scanner.nextInt());` is not really necessary
- You may need to consider a non zero check for `hamsters` !
- Handle Non Ints & -ve numbers in the input
- `else if(){}` is not required when `if(){}` has only single boolean check , just an `else{` is sufficient